# What are the Suitable PHP Framework for Develop Shopping Cart Application for the Jewellery Shop

Tags: php, magento, opencart, shopping-cart

I have a requirement for develop a shopping cart web application for the jewellery shop. I thought to develop this using PHP framework because I have some previous experience with opencart. 
However according to the requirement, price of jewelleries in the shopping cart should be change according to the daily changing (assume this gold rate will input to the system by admin user) gold rate. Also there is a formula to calculate the product (jewellery) price according to the gold rate. 
I am looking for recommendations to achieve this requirement. Can I do this using opencart or do I have to move to another framework like magento or any other?

Comment: I think all PHP framework can do this. You need create your code to do this. If you use opencart, do it with opencart.

Comment: @threeside - Yes doing my own development will resolve this. But I am looking for are there any built in features with frameworks to achieve this requirement.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Can tell only about OpenCart. There is no exact functions like you described in a default version. But:

1. OpenCart has a nice MVC structure and you can easily (depends on your skills level) write your own extension to calculate your formula. For me - OpenCart is 2-3 times less complex and have lower time costs, then Magenta.
2. May be there is a way to use standard functions. You could try to use built-in functions of **currencies** to set gold rate (XAU is a currency too, by the way), and change it from time to time (or automatically). On the customer side will have to set other currency as a default (USD), and the price will change automatically according to USD-XAU exchange rate. Although, there are **options** and **specials** in products, that could help to change price correctly, if the price growth progression is not linear. All of these only a theory. I could answer more accurate if you will write a formula and a scenario of one product behavior.
3. Can try to use existing modules, which will fit your objectives. Like:

   - https://www.opencart.com/index.php?route=marketplace/extension/info&extension_id=27892
   - https://www.opencart.com/index.php?route=marketplace/extension/info&extension_id=20739&filter_member=VipTheme
   - https://www.opencart.com/index.php?route=marketplace/extension/info&extension_id=26807&filter_search=gold